# MVC Session Not Showing in PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing a post back to a controller and setting Sessions.  After they are set, it shows up in the first tab, but when I click next tab that loads another partialview, I do not see sessions set.

order.cshtml with Tabs...

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Total</a></li>       
    </ul>


    <div id="tabs-1">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Partial_General_Tab", Model.GeneralTab);}
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Partial_Item_Tab", Model.ItemTab);}
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        Content for Tab 3 goes here.<br />      
    </div>

</div>
```

Tab 1

```
@model Mvc5.Models.ORDERMetadata

@{
var ordernumber = (int)Session["Order_Number"];
var princid_session = Session["PrincId"];
var custid_session = Session["CustId"];

}  


OrderNumber: @ordernumber <br />
PrinicId: @princid_session <br />
CustID: @custid_session <br />

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Order",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "target"
            }))
{

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        Enter model data here....   

        <button id="editorder" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>



}
```

Tab 2

```
@model Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILSMetadata

@{
var ordernumber = (int)Session["Order_Number"];
var princid_session = Session["PrincId"];
var custid_session = Session["CustId"];

}  


OrderNumber: @ordernumber <br />
PrinicId: @princid_session <br />
CustID: @custid_session <br />

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Items", "Order",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "target"
            }))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        Enter model data here....   

        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />

}
```

Edit Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ORDERMetadata model)
{            
    try
    {       

        // update order
        ....
        db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        Session.Clear();
        Session["Order_Number"] = model.Order_Number;
        Session["PrincId"] = model.Princ_ID;
        Session["CustId"] = model.Cust_ID;

        return PartialView("_Partial_General_Tab", model);

    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");

    }
}
```

Comment: Are those `Session` values set when you initially generate the view?

Comment: Yes, I see them being set, because it shows up in the _Partial_General_Tab.  But when I click the next tab, I do not see them set.

Comment: But are you clicking the next tab before or after you post the first tab? - try setting some dummy values for the `Session` variables in your GET method to test.

Comment: I am clicking the tab after posting to controller.

Comment: I assume the second tab is rendered when you first load the page. Setting or updating `Session` variables when you post the first tab will have no impact on what has already been rendered in the second tab.

Comment: You may be correct that the second tab is rendered when first loading.  When I change it to hit the controller instead of using a partialview, it works fine, but hitting the controller takes too long to load the data.